# Connecting Flutter application with socket.io server

Tags: socket.io, flutter

I need to connect my Flutter app with a socket.io server.

I try to use IOWebSocketChannel but it does not work.

```
var channel = await IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://localhost:80/news");
```

Error returned:

> WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: HttpException:
>   Connection closed before full header was received, uri =
>   http://localhost/news

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io is not an implementation of Web sockets. To interact with socket.io server you need some implementation of socket.io client for flutter.

Here's some of the choices available now:

- [socket_io_common_client](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/socket_io_common_client) (dart port of socket.io)
- [flutter_socket_io](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_socket_io) (plugin)
- [adhara_socket_io](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/adhara_socket_io) (plugin)
- [some implementation on github](https://github.com/AlexeySemigradsky/socket_io) (plugin)